# Python handling specific error codes?

Tags: python, sockets, exception

Hey I'm wondering how to handle specific error codes. For example, `[Errno 111] Connection refused`

I want to catch this specific error in the socket module and print something.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want to get the error code, this seems to do the trick;

```
import errno

try:
    socket_connection()
except socket.error as error:
    if error.errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
        print(os.strerror(error.errno))
    else:
        raise
```

You can look up [`errno` error codes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html).

Comment: On OSX, `ECONNREFUSED` appears to be 61 not 111, so hard-coding the value 111 would be a bad idea for portability.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I am sure that there are more cases like that.

Comment: It's important to have an `else: raise`, otherwise all other error codes will be silently ignored!

Comment: Thanks. This resolved all visual warnings in PyCharm about `errno` not being a valid attribute of `Exception`, even though the code ran perfectly fine.

Comment: @jtpereyda did you mean except: raise ?

Comment: @AnatolyAlekseev no, I mean the same code with an `else: raise` tacked on the end. See @jchl answer for an example. By "all other error codes" I mean all other `socket.error` objects with errorcode != `errno.ECONNREFUSED`

Comment: @jtpereyda this is weird then. I thought else: xxx is called when there were no exception inside try.. block. Docs for Python 3 confirm this. Was it different for python 2?

Comment: @AnatolyAlekseev I mean an `else` that pairs with the `if`. So the else would be at the first indent level, _within_ the `except` block.

Comment: ```os.strerror(error.errno)``` will convert the error code to a message string. i.e.: ```os.strerror(104)``` returns 'Connection reset by peer'

Answer (score 27):

On Unix platforms, at least, you can do the following.

```
import socket, errno
try:
    # Do something...
except socket.error as e:
    if e.errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
        # Handle the exception...
    else:
        raise
```

Before Python 2.6, use `e.args[ 0 ]` instead of `e.errno`.

Comment: Using `e.errno` instead of `e.args[0]` is usually preferred (for exceptions that use errnos).

Comment: I thought that to begin with, but testing it out on my Mac it seemed that `socket.error` didn't have an `errno` member.  It turns out that before Python 2.6, `socket.error` wasn't a subclass of `IOError` and so didn't have an `errno` member.  But of course, before Python 2.6 the `except t as e` syntax wasn't valid either...  I'll update my code.

Answer (score 1):

This seems hard to do reliably/portably but perhaps something like:

```
import socket

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('localhost', 4167))
except socket.error, e:
    if 'Connection refused' in e:
        print '*** Connection refused ***'
```

which yields:

```
$ python socketexception.py 
*** Connection refused ***
```

Pretty yucky though.

Comment: Why would you say this is unreliable/not portable? What is "yucky" about this?

Comment: Because I am not 100% sure that the exception message on Windows would have "Connection refused" in it and not something similar but different like "Could not connect". Not sure if those error messages are standardize (e.g.: in POSIX) and besides not all platforms are necessarily POSIX-compliant.

Comment: (-1) WARNING: This will fail completely in non-english locales.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. This will only work in an English locale. All in all, this is a pretty terrible idea and you should use `errno` like in the above answers.

Comment: +1 for the honesty of saying "Pretty yucky, non-portable, locale-dependent, terrible idea, please don't use" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing on Windows and found myself in the same predicament. But the error message always contains the error number. Using that information I just convert the exception to a string `str(Exception)`, convert the error code I wanna check for to a string `str(socket.errno.ERRORX)` and check if the error code is in the exception.

Example for a connection reset exception:

```
except Exception as errorMessage:
    if str(socket.errno.ECONNRESET) in str(errorMessage):
        print("Connection reset")
        #etc...
```

This avoids locale specific solutions but is still not platform independent unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question, but sadly the answer is quite dissapointing to me at least.

There is no pythonic way to do this.

You'll have to lookup for the error code, but you cannot catch ONLY the code you are looking for. Although you can raise if the errno doesn't match, but still, no pythonic way